# Call QML method from QQuickWidget context

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I use `QQuickWidget` from new Qt 5.3 in my program. And I want to call a function in `QML` from C++.
`QML` file is very simple:

```js
import QtQuick 2.2
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    color: "red"
    function test() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

C++ part also is very simple:

```cpp
QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filePath));
quickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
QVariant returnedValue;
// here I need a reference to some QObject    
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "test",Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue));
```

I tried:

- QObject *obj = quickWidget;
- QObject *obj = quickWidget->rootContext()->contextObject()
- QQuickView view(quickWidget->engine(),this); QObject *obj = view.rootObject();

Nothing helps. The `returnedValue` always is Invalid.

So my quertion is - how can I get this `obj`? Or, in simple words - how can I call my `QML` function from `QQuickWidget` context?

Answer (score 4):

It's absolutely *not* recommended to do this, but you can do something like:

```
Rectangle {
    objectName: "myObj"
}
```

And then from C++ use `view->rootObject()->findChild<QObject *>("myObj");`.

---

Please instead consider using another design, for instance connecting that javascript function to a signal emitted from a C++ object by means of a `Connections` QML element.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i've found the answer.

```js
QObject *obj = quickWidget->rootObject();
```

works for me